# How to correctly implement a port listener as a service in java?

Tags: java, sockets, service, listener, port

I'm tryin to implement a port listener as a service which after getting the string with te data will perform an insert into the DB. I want this to run forever on the server.

So before I use Java Service Wrapper I would like to ask if I'm wrapping the correct code or not, so here is my code and I'm open listen how other people have approached this sames problem.

Right now I'm having an issue where the first time I send data it works perfectly but from the second and on it does nothing, hop you can help me.

```
public class PortToDB {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        DBHandler handler = new DBHandler();
        try{
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(50000);

        } catch (IOException e){
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 50000. Error: " + e);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try{
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();            
        } catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println("Accept failed. " + e);
            System.exit(1);            
        }

        //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;

        while(true){
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                //out.println(inputLine);
                handler.dbInsert(inputLine);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically this would be done with a thread pool and the `.accept()` method would be in a loop handing of the interaction with a new socket to a thread from that pool.  The way you coded above, it will only accept one connection and when that connection is closed, your `main` method will exit.

On a side note, most people would use and existing protocol instead of inventing their own.  Using REST style services over HTTP is a *much* more accepted approach.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I have a lot to read now :) . I will update as soon as make changes to my code.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(50000);
                while(true) {
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    socketReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    new Thread(){
public void run(){
your_method_Name();
}}.start();
            }
```